# findViewById returns null on second call

Tags: android

I've created a ListView with a list of items, each with their own delete button.

I've overridden the getView method in the ArrayAdapter and attached a handler to the delete button.

The problem is, the getView method is being called twice. On the second time, the v.findViewById(DeleteButton) call returns null. I've inspected the view and the ImageButton is there in the hierarchy, but the Id is 0.

Can anyone explain why this is happening please?

**ManualFragment.java**

```
public class ManualFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual, container, false);
        Button addButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        final List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.TextItem, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ManualFragment.this.getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }

                TextView time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextItem);
                time.setText(items.get(position));
                ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
                //THIS LINE THROWS A NULLREF ON SECOND CALL
                delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) v;
                        items.remove(deleteButton.getId());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                delete.setId(position);

                return v;
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        final EditText addText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.AddText);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String value = addText.getText().toString();
                if (!"".equals(value)) {
                    items.add(value);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    addText.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextItem"
            android:layout_width="267dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.89"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/DeleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting it with

```
delete.setId(position)
```

I think you wanted to tag the buttojn with the position

```
delete.setTag(position)
```

Comment: You legend! I feel a little stupid..serves me right for blindly copying a snippet from the web.